# Emacs - Toggling between Visual Markers?

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

I'm trying to figure out if this functionality exists, or if not how difficult it would be to program.

Essentially what I'm looking for is the ability to mark multiple lines in a file with some form of highlighting to point out that they're important lines. From there on it would be great to be able to toggle on/off the marker, and be able to toggle through them - for larger files it would be great to be able to do this for important lines.

The markers don't have to persist, just for that session would be great.

I took a look into the "Overview of Markers" page - but I'm not sure this is exactly what I want, and if it's worth the time to try and implement it if it's not.

Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: [VisibleBookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisibleBookmarks) does something like this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like [`bm.el`](http://www.nongnu.org/bm/) does exactly what you want.

Comment: I use it all the time and it is very helpful. M-x bm-toggle-cycle-all-buffers acts as  on-off for multiple buffers.

Comment: You can also do M-x bm-toggle-buffer-persistence and M-x bm-save to have persistent bookmarks.

Comment: bm.el is simple and just what I need, bookmark+ is too much and I don't know how to use it if I don't use persistent bookmarks.

Answer (score 4):

You want quick, perhaps temporary bookmarks that highlight the location (e.g. line): [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus).

- [Autonamed bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks): hit the same key to create/delete.
- [Temporary bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#TemporaryBookmarks): any bookmarks can be temporary; quick to toggle temp/permanent.
- [Highlighting bookmark locations](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#HighlightingBookmarkLocations): any bookmarks can be highlighted, in various ways.

FWIW, ***Bookmark+*** does everything `bm.el` does, and more.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat similar to what `highlight-regexp` does, except arbitrary text instead of a regexp.  Based on that, I think something like this should work:

```
(defun highlight-text ()
  "Highlight the current region."
  (interactive)
  (let ((overlay (make-overlay (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (overlay-put overlay 'face 'hi-yellow)))
```